# How to solve this (binomial?) series?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Im struggling with this equation. Could someone maybe explain how to get this solution?

$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{-k}{k-1} (p(p-1))^{k-1} = \frac{1}{2p-1}$

My first idea was to use the binomial series, but therefore the $-k$ would have to be fix, which it isn't in my case.

So what would be the best method to solve the equation?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*: $\displaystyle\binom{-k}{k-1}=(-1)^{k-1}\binom{2k-2}{k-1}=2^{2(k-1)}\binom{-\frac12}{k-1}$

Comment: ok, thanks, but then i get $\frac{2}{2p-1}$ because $2^{2k-1}=4^{k-1}\cdot2$ or am i still getting something wrong?

Comment: Oops, missing a bracket there.  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I was able to solve the equation with this. But how do I obtain this hint? Is that common knowledge or is there a specific trick?

Comment: The binomial coefficients $\binom{\pm1/2}{k}$ is standard common knowledge because of expanding $\sqrt{1+x}$ or $\frac1{\sqrt{1+x}}$.  $\binom{2k}{k}=(-4)^k\binom{-1/2}{k}$ comes up often enough.